# How to use polymer to test webcam,audio, and microphone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, polymer, mocha.js, web-component-tester

I am looking for a way to use Polymer web component tester, to test a users Webcam (if connected), audio (headphone, speakers), and Microphone (connected or not) on a web page.

I have searched SO for a while trying to find something that would work; however, have came up with no results.

I am looking for examples, or documentation on how to do this (if possible)